# java Optional checking nulls

Tags: java, option-type

I was under the impression Optional.ofNullable(response.getSubscriber()) can also determine if the object response is null, but it can't

Is there a better way to check that response and response.getSubscriber is present ?

```
  public Subscriber generateSubscriber(SPRGetSubscriberResponse response) {
        if (response != null) {
            Optional<SPRSubscriber> option = Optional.ofNullable(response.getSubscriber());
            if (option.isPresent()) {
                Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();
                //...copy members from response to subscriber

                return subscriber;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just test `if (response.getSubscriber() == null)`?

Comment: @JernejK He wants to avoid IF conditions and extra code ,,

Comment: I am looking at the [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) and it seems like you have a text book example. Did you try to debug, because the code does not lie.

Comment: Agree with @JernejK. There's absolutely no point in using `Optional` locally in a method like this. I'd only consider using `Optional` if you're exposing the optional value as part of your API, or if you're consuming another API's optional values.

Comment: Objects.isNull(anyInstance) can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing conditionals and `Optional` in a way that gets all of the clumsiness and none of the fluency. To use just the basic features, no `Optional`:

```
if (response != null && response.getSubscriber != null)
```

In Groovy:

```
response?.subscriber // null-safe navigation to collapse your conditional
```

With Java 8 goodness:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(response)
    .map(SPRGetSubscriberResponse::getSubscriber)
    .map(original -> { /* return the copied version */ })
    .orElse(null);
```